# Поиск стал медленнее после добавления индекса

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb, индексы

В коллекции mongodb хранятся документы вида :

```
{url: "/url", ip: "0.0.0.0", ua:"useragent", time: 51}
```

делаю выборку следующим кодом

```
collection.aggregate([
{ $group: { _id: "$url", count: { $sum: 1}, time: { $sum: "$time"} }},
{ $project: { _id: 1, count:1, time: { $round : [{$divide: ["$time", "$count"]}, 0] } } },
{ $sort: { count : -1 } },
{ $limit: 100}
]).toArray(callback);
```

При `700.000` документов запрос занимает 3 секунды, что как-то очень долго, добавил индекс на поле `url`

```
collection.createIndex({ url: 1})
```

После этого запросы стали обрабатываться в 2 раза дольше, после удаления индекса, время выполнения вернулось к 3 секундам.

1. Как ускорить выполнение запроса?
2. Почему добавление индекса привело к ухудшению результатов?